# Bootstrap tooltip not working with error 'tooltip is not a function' (MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am implementing tooltip using bootstrap. My code looks like:

View:

```
<div class="CompleteRegistrationHeadingText glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test!"></div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

I am rendering js file and css from layout:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

My bundles are as below:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/DocThemes/*Layout.css", "~/Content/DocThemes/Utility.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.*", "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.*"));
```

But when I run my website, I get below error:
[image]

And tooltip functionality does not work.

Am I doing anything wrong in implementation?

Comment: Have you checked the source to ensure that your bundles have been included in the page correctly? Also note that *both* jQueryUI and Bootstrap have `tooltip()` methods - you may be getting a conflict.

Comment: plus always render your `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` before rendering any other scripts!

Comment: I have expanded the script node in snapshot. All required css and js seems to be loaded correctly. To avoid conflict should I remove jquery-ui reference for this page?

Comment: And if tooltip is common function in jquery-ui and bootstrap, in that case also last rendered one(which is bootstrap) should be executed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: replace that $ with jQuery. i know its silly but just try.

Comment: i think the problem is either your jquery is not initializing properly or it is initializing after you above statement so it is not able to refer that "$" sign.